# Find the number of the number of distinct local maxima of a 3D function in R

Tags: r, algorithm

I am a starter learner of R programming. Now I am working on finding the number of the number of distinct local maxima of a 3D function.

```
# This form takes (x, y) and k as three parameters.
e = function(x, y, k = 120) {
  ifelse (test=((abs(x) > k) | (abs(y) > k)),
          yes=0,
          no=(1 - x/k)*(1 - y/k)*(1 + x/k)*(1 + y/k)*
          (-(y + 47) * sin(sqrt(abs(y + x/2 + 47))) - x*sin(sqrt(abs(x - (y + 47)))))
          )
}

# This form takes (x, y) as the 2-vector x and k as a second parameter.
f = function(x, k = 120) {
  ifelse (test=((abs(x[1]) > k) | (abs(x[2]) > k)),
          yes=0,
          no=(1 - x[1]/k)*(1 - x[2]/k)*(1 + x[1]/k)*(1 + x[2]/k)*
          (-(x[2] + 47) * sin(sqrt(abs(x[2] + x[1]/2 + 47))) - x[1]*sin(sqrt(abs(x[1] - (x[2] + 47)))))
          )
}
```

The code above is the function. The range between `x` and `y` both are `(-k, k)`, `k` equals 120

The 3D graph has been created

```
plot3d(e, c(-k, k), c(-k, k), alpha=1)
```

I have found a local max by `optim`.

So I thought to write a loop to go through `optim` every time and writes it into a `data.frame`, and then check the length of the data frame. But it seems will cost a lot of time and it's too complicated.

Could someone please give me some advice on this so that I can do it in a more clean and efficient way?

Comment: There is no general way to find all local maximums. For example, `optim` function finds a local maximum, not all.  So this won't allow you to find the number of distinct local maximums.
What you can do is to calculate the function value with many pairs of x and y and check if they are local maximums (i.e. larger than the neighboring points).

Comment: Why not do a grid search on a fairly coarse grid?